# Istio ingress rewrite sub paths similar to nginx ingress

Tags: networking, url-rewriting, routes, istio, nginx-ingress

Is there a way in Istio where the subpaths accessed by the application can be specified using a wildcard entry?
For ex, in [nginx-ingress](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/), this sub route rewrite is handled by mentioning the path as  `path: /something(/|$)(.*)`
We have configured a VirtualService which rewrites https://IP/route to https://IP/. The app further calls others APIs to render the dashboardds etc. These APIs run at `/topology` or `/api` etc paths. We might not be having the knowledge of the sub-paths that many of the apps use. In this case, is there a way in which any wildcards can be specified (similar to nginx ingress) so that we do not have to worry on the app specific routing and Istio can handle the rest of the sub paths?

Comment: This could be achieved with custom envoy filter like http lua filter. More info [here](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/envoy-filter/).

Comment: Cant it be done at the virtual service level itself? Instead of defining a filter? @PiotrMalec